# Making for loop in xtend template, to print in same line

Tags: templates, for-loop, line, xtend

So if I have

```
«FOR number: numbers»
    «number»
 «ENDFOR»
```

It will print every number in new line, how do I make it print numbers in the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not suitable for your usecase, but did you try

```
«FOR number: numbers»«number»«ENDFOR»
```

Another option is to use `«numbers.join()»`

Comment: «FOR number: numbers»«number»«ENDFOR» worked. I feel stupid now. I tried this, but not with everything, now when I deleted all breaks it works as intended. I have 360 symbols long method in one row, but its better than weird spacing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's often a good idea to just extract a method for very long expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop construction

```
«FOR number: numbers»
    «number»
«ENDFOR»
```

has been mainly created to generates values on many lines. If you need to concatenate values on a single line, join() is a better option:

```
«numbers.join»
```

Shorter, cleaner, more clear. And you can also give a separator parameter

```
«numbers.join(", ")»
```